# Why might unconstrained LR/SC sequences never succeed on some RISCV implementations?

Tags: riscv

A concept of *constrained LR/SC loops* appears in "A" standard Extension for Atomic Instructions in RISC-V Unprivileged ISA. According to this specification,*constrained LR/SC loops* has some properties: fitting within 64 contiguous instruction bytes, disallowing other ld/sc or backward jumps in the loop...etc
LR/SC sequences that do not lie within constrained LR/SC loops are unconstrained and might never succeed on some  implementations.

My question is what is the reason that the unconstrained LR/SC sequences might never succeed?

Comment: I've removed the tags "lr" and "sc" as they refer to something else. Please be more careful with the use of tags.

Comment: Clearly you can't expect arbitrary sequences of LR/SC to eventually succeed. For example, if you execute 2 billion instructions between the LR and SC, the system will take a hardware timer tick at some point during those 2 billion instructions and clear the lock state as part of interrupt handling.